# Replace part of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I replace:

```
var url = "http://localhost:2879/ServiceDonneesArchive.svc/Installations(1002)?$expand=Stations";
```

by:

```
var nameInstallation = 1002;
    var url = "http://localhost:2879/ServiceDonneesArchive.svc/Installations(nameInstallation)?$expand=Stations";
```

Comment: are you asking how to replace something in a string to another value?

Answer (score 1):

Why do this the hard way? For this use case, simple concatenation would be very readable:

```
var nameInstallation = 1002;
var url = 'http://localhost:2879/ServiceDonneesArchive.svc/Installations(' + nameInstallation + ')?$expand=Stations';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). To replace any instances of `"nameInstallation"` in your `url` variable with `"1002"`:

```
url = url.replace(/nameInstallation/g, "1002");
```

Or if you have the replacement value in a variable `nameInstallation = 1002`:

```
url = url.replace(/nameInstallation/g, nameInstallation);
```

EDIT: As pointed out by David Thomas, you probably don't need the `g` flag on the regular expression that is the first parameter to `.replace()`. With this "global" flag it will replace all instances of the text "nameInstallation". Without the flag it would replace only the first instance. So either include it or leave it off according to your needs. (If you only need to replace the first occurrence you also have the option of passing a string as the first parameter rather than a regex.)

Comment: Do you need the `g`? I realise that, in future, his use-case may change, but it seems unnecessary for this case. In any case, it's probably worth explaining what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out this javascript function

```
// from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/201899/String-Format-in-JavaScript
        String.prototype.format = function (args) {
            var str = this;
            return str.replace(String.prototype.format.regex, function(item) {
                var intVal = parseInt(item.substring(1, item.length - 1));
                var replace;
                if (intVal >= 0) {
                    replace = args[intVal];
                } else if (intVal === -1) {
                    replace = "{";
                } else if (intVal === -2) {
                    replace = "}";
                } else {
                    replace = "";
                }
                return replace;
            });
        };
        String.prototype.format.regex = new RegExp("{-?[0-9]+}", "g");
```

and use:

```
var url = "http://localhost:2879/ServiceDonneesArchive.svc/Installations{0}?$expand=Stations";
var nameInstallation = 1002;
var result = url.format(nameInstallation );
```

Comment: it does not work. Is there not an easier way? I already understands not your function. Can you explain that? thank you

Comment: as far as I know you have to create a method in order to simulate string.Format java's one. Check this post, I tried it out and works: http://frogsbrain.blogspot.com.es/2007/04/javascript-stringformat-method.html

Comment: ok I'll try. But it's amazing they did not think to code this feature that seems handy.